# Consistently append new rows to a dataframe, df_A, based on the differences between df_A and df_B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, dask

I have data frames for dumps every 10 mins in the day. Example

```
2019-08-28 06:00:13 SCHOOL_20190828...
2019-08-28 06:10:15 SCHOOL_20190828...
2019-08-28 06:20:14 SCHOOL_20190828...
2019-08-28 06:30:13 SCHOOL_20190828...
2019-08-28 06:40:15 SCHOOL_20190828...
... ...
2019-09-28 05:10:13 SCHOOL_20190928...
2019-09-28 05:20:13 SCHOOL_20190928...
2019-09-28 05:30:13 SCHOOL_20190928...
2019-09-28 05:40:14 SCHOOL_20190928...
2019-09-28 05:50:13 SCHOOL_20190928...
```

Each successive dataframe has about 2 rows difference(if they happen to be from the same day)

I want to read the first data frame in a day(A), compare it to the next data frame, (B)  and append the new rows to my data frame, A. I want to continue until I read in all the data frames for that day. Move on to the next day and do the same. I will then append all the outputs from the various days.

Examples of data frames

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df_A = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}, {'a':10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30},{'a':2,'b':4,'c':6}]) 
df_B = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}, {'a':10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30},{'a':2,'b':4,'c':6},{'a':0,'b':12,'c':16}])
df_C = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3},{'a':21,'b':12,'c':9}])
```

```
df_A                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[3]: 
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  10  20  30
2   2   4   6

df_B                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[8]: 
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  10  20  30
2   2   4   6
3   0  12  16

df_C                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[9]: 
    a   b  c
0   1   2  3
1  21  12  9
```

I want my final data frame to be

```
df                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[10]: 
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  10  20  30
2   2   4   6
3   0  12  16
4  21  12   9
```

I want the most time-efficient way to do this since the data frames are quite a lot(About 5000)

Currently, I just read all the dumps using dask and drop duplicates.

```
ddf = dd.read_csv(path, storage_options=storage_opts, assume_missing=True).drop_duplicates().compute()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pd.concat and drop_duplicates to do that like below

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['0', '1', '2', '3'], ['1', '10', '20', '30'], ['2', '2', '4', '6']], columns=('id', 'a', 'b', 'c'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['0', '1', '2', '3'], ['1', '10', '20', '30'], ['2', '2', '4', '6'], ['3', '0', '12', '16']], columns=('id', 'a', 'b', 'c'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['0', '1', '2', '3'], ['1', '21', '12', '9']], columns=('id', 'a', 'b', 'c'))

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
 id   a   b   c
0  0   1   2   3
1  1  10  20  30
2  2   2   4   6
3  3   0  12  16
1  1  21  12   9
```